# `nvidia-driver` install failing due to kernel module build error

Tags: linux, debian, apt, build, kernel-module

#### This wasn't something I did, but a bug in Debian.

See [this thread](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=158200) on the matter. The kernel update from 6.1.0-17 to 6.1.0-18 broke the nvidia kernel module. I must have coincidentally updated my kernel while doing other work and assumed I messed something up. What worked for me and many others was to simply install backports 6.5 kernel:

- Add backports to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by adding this line:

  ```
  deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports main
  ```
- Update apt: `sudo apt update`
- Install the new images: `sudo apt install -t bookworm-backports linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64`
- Reboot into the new kernel version
- Remove the bad kernel versions: `sudo apt remove linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64 linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64`
  *Substitute `amd64` for your architecture*
- Install your nvidia drivers (either through `apt` or a manually-downloaded `.run`.

#### Original post:

---

I recently was troubleshooting ALVR, and somehow fell deep into a black hole of kernel versions and Linux boot failures.

Following something I did, apt kept failing to install things, running some sort of `make` command for no reason. I didn't know it then, but I had unwittingly installed some sort of Kernel nonsense that was causing dkms issues, and would eventually lead to a kernel panic following a reboot.

I've fiddled around with a lot of things in TTY5 of an older kernel version that I got to with grub. Foolishly, I didn't document any of it, and I didn't commit much of it to memory. When things are this bad, I'm kind of panicking. However, I know where I'm at right now:

I've got `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` installed, both providing the 6.1.0-18-amd64 flavors. However, installing `nvidia-driver` fails due to some sort of Kernel module build error. The error says to refer to a file `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/525.147.05/build/make.log`, which has hundreds of lines, but this error at the end:

```
ERROR: modpost: GPL-incompatible module nvidia.ko uses GPL-only symbol '__rcu_read_lock'
ERROR: modpost: GPL-incompatible module nvidia.ko uses GPL-only symbol '__rcu_read_unlock'
```

I think I made a single misstep then got myself deeper trying to identify and revert it. I'm not sure what I could have done, or what I can do from here. Please help. :'(

P.S.
Let me know if you need any more information. I'm swimming in a sea of command outputs with no idea what does and doesn't matter.

And, be honest, would it just be easier to reinstall Debian? I've got an independent `home` partition, so it wouldn't be too destructive.

Edit 1:
I can actually enter tty5 in the messed up kernel version, so it isn't necessarily failing to boot, it's just failing to go to GDM.
Output of `source /etc/os-release; echo $PRETTY_NAME, $(uname -a)` as suggested by Hannu:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm), Linux devin-pc 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit 2:
[Here's a pastebin of the output of journalctl](https://pastebin.com/NSnhSZr5). Looks like there's a lot of juicy info here.  I'll do some of my own digging.

Edit 3:
Call me impatient, but I'm giving up. I need my computer more than I need the data on the root partition.

Comment: so, Debian, to define more precisely, do `$ source /etc/os-release; echo $PRETTY_NAME, $(uname -a)` - generally, a self compiled kernel (if you have that here) will drive you into that black hole of dependency errors. You might actually have better success in finding a remedy if you look at **ONLY the first appearing** warning or error - and try to fix that.

Comment: The Linux version I'm trying to use, 6.1.0-18, is the one that fails to boot. Running the given command gives me info about the kernel version -17 that can run in tty5.

Comment: Wait! I just discovered that I'm actually able to pull up tty5 on the messed up Kernel version!